# how to pass values from class file to showModalDialogue in sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have created following code for context menu.There is a template where i have created a context menu.When i click on the context menu,It will get the field value and should display it in the ASPX file which i have included in this code.I am able to loop through the fields in the item but am unable to pass to the aspx file.

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

using Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands; using Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;

namespace ContextMenus
{
    public class CustomMenuType : Command
    {
        string ItemName;

        public override void Execute(CommandContext context)
        {
            if (context.Items.Length == 1)
            {
                Item _item = context.Items[0];
                System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection _parameters = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
                _parameters["id"] = _item.ID.ToString();

                Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.Start(this, "Run", _parameters);

                string ItemDatabase = _item.Database.Name;
                string ItemParent1 = _item.ID.ToString();

                Sitecore.Data.Database master1 = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase(ItemDatabase);

                string ItemPath = _item.Parent.Paths.FullPath;

                Sitecore.Data.Items.Item home1 = master1.GetItem(ItemPath);
                ContextMenus.Entities.TemplateEntity objEntity = new ContextMenus.Entities.TemplateEntity();
                foreach (Sitecore.Data.Items.Item child in home1.Children)
                {
                    objEntity.Fname = child["First Name"];
                    objEntity.Lname = child["Last Name"];
                    objEntity.Dept = child["Department"];
                    objEntity.Age = child["Age"];
                }
            }
        }

        protected void Run(Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPipelineArgs args)
        {
            Sitecore.Text.UrlString _url = new Sitecore.Text.UrlString("/ContextMenus/CustomContextMenu.aspx");
            _url.Append("id", args.Parameters["id"]);
            Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.ShowModalDialog(_url.ToString());
        }

        public override CommandState QueryState(CommandContext context)
        {
            foreach (Item _item in context.Items)
            {
                if (_item.TemplateID.ToString() != "{9F8334D3-01F3-4159-AA4A-BF513AC3E9FB}")
                {
                    return CommandState.Hidden;
                }
            }

            return base.QueryState(context);
        }
    }
}
```

I have written following code in code behind file[CustomContextMenu.aspx.cs].It will just get the data from my entity[TemplateEntity] and I would like to display this in aspx file.

```
ContextMenus.Entities.TemplateEntity ObjTempEntity = new
ContextMenus.Entities.TemplateEntity();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("First Name").Append("=").Append(ObjTempEntity.Fname);
Response.Write(sb.ToString());

StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
sb1.Append("Last Name").Append("=").Append(ObjTempEntity.Lname);
Response.Write(sb1.ToString());

StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
sb2.Append("Department Name").Append("=").Append(ObjTempEntity.Dept);
Response.Write(sb2.ToString());

StringBuilder sb3 = new StringBuilder();
sb3.Append("Age").Append("=").Append(ObjTempEntity.Age);
Response.Write(sb3.ToString());
```

I am able to loop through the Item field values.I want to dispaly those values in the aspx file.How to pass Field name with values in showModalDialogue.

1.I have hardcoded the Template ID in the queryState method.I am getting the field values of that item in the execute method.

2.I have created CustomContextMenu aspx file where i want to show the field values.How to transfer values from the entityclass[TemplateEntity] to CustomMenuType.aspx.cs file.

Comment: Why don't you just pass the guid of the item to the ASPX modal and then get the item from Sitecore in the code behind? Then you have access to all the fields rather than passing individual fields

Answer (score 0):

Everything in your Execute method after the call to `Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.Start` appears to be wasted effort.  As far as I can tell, it would not have any effect on anything.

You are already passing the ID of the item to the modal dialog.  You should be able to use `Request.QueryString["id"]` to get that ID in the codebehind of your dialog.  You can then retrieve the item and get the values of its fields.